# How to revert Android kill-switched Nvidia Shield tablet?

Tags: recovery-mode, nvidia-shield

Apparently Nvidia decided to kill most of their shipped Shield tablets because of a battery defect. Considering my shield already died, does anyone have any idea on how exactly could this be reverted?

Comment: [Can you access the fastboot? If not, then your tablet is probably gone for good.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/shield-tablet/general/kill-kill-switch-shield-tablet-xx-t3179489)

Comment: @AndrewT. How to check if I can get to fastboot? Anyway, the hardware is there. Surely there must be a way...

Comment: To get to fastboot, hold volume down+power at the same time. Anyway, "*The only way to fix this would be through nvflash, and using it requires the SBK that is unique to each device and that only Nvidia knows, so it's pretty unlikely that we'll ever be able to fix these deactivated tablets.*". I really hope for the best that this issue can be resolved easily, but it doesn't seem so...

Comment: @AndrewT. I see... I'll try and come up with something when I have the time...

Comment: any luck ? or any news ?